Embedding Tableau view using Embedding api in Experience cloud
I am trying to embed a Tableau view, using embedding api v3 in Lightning communities bases on LWR. I have created an LWC component with the following markup and JS.
The reason I am using LWC is that I have to use dynamic URL for the view, otherwise I could have used lightning-viz component.
HTML
<template>        
    <tableau-viz id="tableauViz"       
        src='https://public.tableau.com/views/Superstore_embedded_800x800/Overview'    
        toolbar="bottom" hide-tabs>
    </tableau-viz>    
</template>

JS
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";
import tableauEmbedding from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/tableauEmbedding";
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import {
  TableauViz,
  TableauEventType
} from 'https://<my-server>/javascripts/api/tableau.embedding.3.latest.min.js';


export default class testLWC extends LightningElement {
  
}

When trying to deploy the code, I get following error:

Invalid import 'https:///javascripts/api/tableau.embedding.3.latest.min.js'. No '.' in module reference or start relative path with ./


My assumption is that a similar pattern to this https://github.com/4an70m/d3-lwc-quick-examples (for D3) would be required i.e. a loadScript of the library added to your org as a static resource. Or have you found a specifically LWC example that you are copying? If so do add a link to that.
PS
Looks like this Tableau Embedding API Community might be a good place to search and perhaps also post your question. Oh I see you already have.

Hi @Keith - examples are there in the tableau embedding api link, present in my question.

Hi @Mahmood, I didn't see an example there where the environment looked like LWR or LWC; those environments are more restrictive than most JavaScript environments.

Hi @ Kieth - that’s correct but the idea should be same in LWC. Or at least i tried it that way
